# Angular2.0.0 - get the query string(with ?) from url hashtag location strategy

Tags: angular, query-string, angular2-router

I use `angular 2.0.0` and I have an URL like this:

http://localhost:4200/?sptoken=MY_TOKEN#/resetPassword/

I want to get `MY_TOKEN` from it. I tried everything i could find here but I only get "`undefined`".

The second problem is that I use hashtag location strategy and if i access the URL like this it gets transformed to http://localhost:4200/#/resetPassword/ (the query string is gone), the only time when i could access this token is in the main component before it gets transformed but I don't know how to get it, most of the things I found are referring to the matrix notation query parameters.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can solve this?

This is my code:

```
export class ResetPasswordComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParams['sptoken']); // when i don't use 
                                               //HashLocationStrategy it logs the token
  }

}

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router, public configService: ConfigService, private cookieService: CookieService,private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParams['sptoken']);
  }
}
```

And my routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: UrlPaths.HELLO, component: HelloComponent, canActivate: [PrivatePageGuard]},
    {path: UrlPaths.LOGIN, component: LoginComponent},
    {path: UrlPaths.MAIN_PAGE, component: AppComponent},
    {path: UrlPaths.FORGOT_PASSWORD, component: ForgotPasswordComponent},
    {path: UrlPaths.RESET_PASSWORD, component: ResetPasswordComponent}
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);


export const UrlPaths = Object.freeze({
    LOGIN: 'login',
    HELLO: 'hello',
    FORGOT_PASSWORD: 'forgotPassword',
    RESET_PASSWORD: 'resetPassword',
    MAIN_PAGE: ''
});
```

I have also tried to try to get the token in the main component by using this URL: `http://localhost:4200/?sptoken=MY_TOKEN#` but it happens the same

Comment: `sptoken` do you set it with `queryParams`???

Comment: yes, i use an external api for authentication and password reset and they send me the token through query params

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of a redirect. Query parameters are not retained for redirects. Instead of a redirect add a dummy component, in the component get the query parameters from the activated route and then do the redirect with `router.navigate()`

Comment: I tried doing that but it doesn't work because of the HashLocationStrategy, it doesn't recognise the query string, when i don't use it it works but I have to use it

Comment: I don't think this is related to `HashLocationStrategy`. `HashLocationStrategy` works the same as `PathLocationStrategy`, just the URL representation is different (and the later requires server support). Perhaps you're looking at the wrong level. Queryparameters are only available on top-level routes.

Comment: I have only top-level routes, I tried even in the main app component but I still couldn't get it

Comment: How does the URL look like including the query string? Can you please edit your question and add the code there that demonstrates what you tried?

Comment: Please try `this.route.queryParams.forEach((p) => console.log(p['sptoken']));`

Comment: I still get `undefined` with `this.route.queryParams.forEach((p) => console.log(p['sptoken']));`

Comment: Then I don't know.